# Is it possible to access console on Tshock server which is running in docker container?

Tags: bash, docker

So my main goal is to access Tshock console so i could run some commands on the server directly.

From what i found as soon as the command to run the server is executed there is no option to get back to the console so:

I'd like to run the server in screen mode.

Dockerfile is basicly running some bash script but i'm getting errors when i'm trying to add "screen" to it. I'm getting ***"bootstrap.sh: 33: bootstrap.sh: Syntax error: "fi" unexpected (expecting "then")
Entering script"***

I've tried everything i could found on google but nothing works :( This is my first time when i'm doing any scripting in bash so i would be grateful for understanding :)

Here is the link to original repo: https://github.com/ryansheehan/terraria/blob/master/tshock/bootstrap.sh

I would be glad for any hints on how to make this script working or if there is any other simplier option to access the console of the server :)

I've added extra line in dockerfile to download screen so it looks like that now:

```
FROM alpine:3.11.6 AS base

RUN apk add --update-cache \
    unzip

# add the bootstrap file
COPY bootstrap.sh /tshock/bootstrap.sh

ENV TSHOCKVERSION=v4.4.0-pre12
ENV TSHOCKZIP=TShock4.4.0_Pre12_Terraria1.4.0.5.zip

# Download and unpack TShock
ADD https://github.com/Pryaxis/TShock/releases/download/$TSHOCKVERSION/$TSHOCKZIP /
RUN unzip $TSHOCKZIP -d /tshock && \
    rm $TSHOCKZIP && \
    chmod +x /tshock/TerrariaServer.exe && \
    # add executable perm to bootstrap
    chmod +x /tshock/bootstrap.sh

FROM mono:6.8.0.96-slim

LABEL maintainer="Ryan Sheehan <rsheehan@gmail.com>"

# documenting ports
EXPOSE 7777 7878

# env used in the bootstrap
ENV CONFIGPATH=/root/.local/share/Terraria/Worlds
ENV LOGPATH=/tshock/logs
ENV WORLD_FILENAME=""

# Allow for external data
VOLUME ["/root/.local/share/Terraria/Worlds", "/tshock/logs", "/plugins"]

# install nuget to grab tshock dependencies
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y nuget && \
    apt-get install -y screen 
#   rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/*

# copy game files
COPY --from=base /tshock/ /tshock/

# Set working directory to server
WORKDIR /tshock

# run the bootstrap, which will copy the TShockAPI.dll before starting the server
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/sh", "bootstrap.sh" ]
```

And here is my modified code for bootstrap.sh :

```
#!/bin/sh
  echo "Entering script"
  if [ -z "$STY" ];then
      echo "Opening screen mode ..."
      exec screen -dm -S terraria bin/bash "$0"
  else
      echo "Continuing with script in screen mode"
      echo "\nBootstrap:\nworld_file_name=$WORLD_FILENAME\nconfigpath=$CONFIGPATH\nlogpath=$LOGPATH\n"
      echo "Copying plugins..."
      cp -Rfv /plugins/* ./ServerPlugins
      
      WORLD_PATH="/root/.local/share/Terraria/Worlds/$WORLD_FILENAME"
  
      if [ -z "$WORLD_FILENAME" ]; then  
        echo "No world file specified in environment WORLD_FILENAME."
        if [ -z "$@" ]; then 
          echo "Running server setup..."
        else
          echo "Running server with command flags: $@"
        fi
        mono --server --gc=sgen -O=all TerrariaServer.exe -configpath "$CONFIGPATH" -logpath "$LOGPATH" "$@" 
      else
        echo "Environment WORLD_FILENAME specified"
        if [ -f "$WORLD_PATH" ]; then
          echo "Loading to world $WORLD_FILENAME..."
          mono --server --gc=sgen -O=all TerrariaServer.exe -configpath "$CONFIGPATH" -logpath "$LOGPATH" -world "$WORLD_PATH" "$@" 
        else
          echo "Unable to locate $WORLD_PATH.\nPlease make sure your world file is volumed into docker: -v <path_to_world_file>:/root/.local/share/Terraria/Worlds"
          exit 1
        fi
      fi
  fi
```

After removing empty spaces as **@KamilCuk** suggested the script is running but the screen doesn't seem to be working.

Here is the output from console:

```
PS D:\TerrariaServer\Source\terraria\tshock> docker run --rm -p 7777:7777 -v D:/TerrariaServer/World:/root/.local/share/Terraria/Worlds --name="terraria" terraria-image  -world /root/.local/share/Terraria/Worlds/TestWorld.wld
Entering screen mode
+ [ -z  ]
+ echo Entering screen mode
+ screen -d -m -S terraria bin/bash bootstrap.sh
+ echo Screen mode activated
+ echo Continuing with script in screen mode
+ echo \nBootstrap:\nworld_file_name=\nconfigpath=/root/.local/share/Terraria/Worlds\nlogpath=/tshock/logs\n
+ echo Copying plugins...
+ cp -Rfv /plugins/* ./ServerPlugins
Screen mode activated
Continuing with script in screen mode

Bootstrap:
world_file_name=
configpath=/root/.local/share/Terraria/Worlds
logpath=/tshock/logs

Copying plugins...
cp: cannot stat '/plugins/*': No such file or directory
+ WORLD_PATH=/root/.local/share/Terraria/Worlds/
+ [ -z  ]
+ echo No world file specified in environment WORLD_FILENAME.
+ [ -z -world /root/.local/share/Terraria/Worlds/TestWorld.wld ]
+ echo Running server with command flags: -world /root/.local/share/Terraria/Worlds/TestWorld.wld
+ mono --server --gc=sgen -O=all TerrariaServer.exe -configpath /root/.local/share/Terraria/Worlds -logpath /tshock/logs -world /root/.local/share/Terraria/Worlds/TestWorld.wld
No world file specified in environment WORLD_FILENAME.
Running server with command flags: -world /root/.local/share/Terraria/Worlds/TestWorld.wld
Error Logging Enabled.
TerrariaAPI Version: 2.1.0.0 (Protocol v1.4.0.5 (230), OTAPI 1.4.0.5)
[TShock] Info Config path has been set to /root/.local/share/Terraria/Worlds
[TShock] Info Log path has been set to /tshock/logs
TShock was improperly shut down. Please use the exit command in the future to prevent this.
TShock 4.4.0.0 (Go to sleep Patrikkk, Icy, Chris, Death, Axeel, Zaicon, hakusaro, Zack, and Yoraiz0r <3) now running.
AutoSave Enabled
Backups Enabled
Welcome to TShock for Terraria!
TShock comes with no warranty & is free software.
You can modify & distribute it under the terms of the GNU GPLv3.
[Server API] Info Plugin TShock v4.4.0.0 (by The TShock Team) initiated.
Terraria Server v1.4.0.5

Resetting game objects 1%
Resetting game objects 2%
Resetting game objects 3%
...
```

Comment: `if [ -z "$@" ]` is strange and will result in an error with different number then 1 argument. Anyway, I guess your editor adds dos line endings to the file. Remove them?

Comment: if [ -z "$@" ] was originaly in the script and it seems to be working fine so i'm not touching it :P i've removed white spaces and it don't throw the error anymore but docker container dies imidiately after it starts

Answer (score 1):

I'm not directly seenig major issues with your entrypoint script. But I want provide some steps I would do to hopefully resolve these kind of issues:

1. Avoid the line `f [ -z "$@" ]`.
   See [here](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2198) why.

   Suggestion: `f [ -z "$*" ]`
2. Also this line is problematic too: `echo "Running server with command flags: $@"`
   See [here](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2145) why.

   Suggestion: `echo "Running server with command flags: $*"`

---

3. Sometimes it can help, to enter the container and "play around". This allows you to work in your docker container like you would do in any normal Linux shell.

   *Have a look at the [-interactive, -i](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) option for `docker run`.*

   **Example**

   If you want to start your container, you can run e. g. run a `bash` (...or `sh`, or whatever shell you are using):

   ```sh
   docker run -it <img_name> <arguments> bash
   ```

   This also works with `exec` when your container is already running and you want to enter it.

   ```sh
   docker exec -it <container_id> bash
   ```
4. Try the `bash -x` option when invoking your entrypoint script to get a verbose output. Sometimes it helps finding the error.

   ```
   ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-x" "bootstrap.sh" ]
   ```

Comment: Thanks agentsmith :) i've changed $@ to $*

Comment: I've used interactive mode already to play with the container, the issue is that after executting the command which runs the server the console quits server console and i can't enter it back which means i can't excecute commands on the server even though i can execute commands on the container, that's why i'm trying to run the server in screen mode so i could execute commands on the container in one "screen" and on the server on another "screen" :)

Comment: Beside the two things I pointed out the entrypoint looks fine. I guess the problem is the terminal multiplexer. Using them is not that trivial in docker containers. But: What happens if you invoke the screen command in interactive mode (`-i` option)? Does this work?

Comment: So after i run docker run command i'm getting output from server console after it boots i can't do anything else then hit ctrl + c as first of all it displays in my local console instead of container console and secondly it's not interactive

Comment: When i do "docker exec -it <container> bash" i'm entering container bash and when i'm executing "screen -ls" i'm getting: "No Sockets found in /run/screen/S-root."

Comment: Okay, this seems to be a `screen` issue. You can try to use `tmux` instead (follow [this description](https://gist.github.com/ptrj/b54b8cdd34f632028e669a1e71bc03b8)) and see if it work, but no guarantee for that...

Comment: It seems that everything is working fine but on default screen terminates after running script so i need to add something which will hold the session for me